# Pre sales (Public and Private) ERC20

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I am developing a currency for my game, and I would like to know how pre-sales (public and private) works, what do I need to program in my smart contract?

Is there an example model for this type of situation? I'm researching and I'm not finding something that helps me understand smart contract programming.

Comment: When you say Pre sales, do you mean an ICO ?

Comment: I don't know, I believe it is, it's just that I always see NFT games saying "Presales".

Comment: @Crazy It depends on how much decentralization you want. Some projects use a wallet where interested people would send payments. You could process the incoming transactions and when deploying the token reserve tokens for them in some proportion. More advanced is to use a crowdsale contract and send them a temporary token until the final ERC20 is developed.